# HTML encoding in C# -- is there any other way

Tags: c#

Is there any way to do HTML encoding in C# when characters like apostrophes encoded like `&apos;` instead of `&#39;` as in case of `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method?

I have the DB that contains a string like this:

```
str&apos;str
```

and I need to select it via SQL query when the user type "str'str" in the `TextBox`. So I want to encode it to the same string first and select it via `LIKE` operator then.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you mean "is there any other way"? A dozen, but anything specific?

Comment: Why not use the method you mention yourself?

Comment: @Patrick Hofman @Alejandro I need to encode characters like apostrophes as `&apos;` instead of `&#39;`

Comment: Why? They are the same.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman I need to execute SQL query to the DB contains `&apos;` instead of `&#39;`

Comment: Again: why? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @Patrick Hofman I've updated the question

Comment: @PatrickHofman He stores strings containing "&apos;" as a string, for example "Mike&apos;s". Now when from his UI he wants to search "Mike's", he wants to convert the search term to "Mike&apos;s" instead of "Mike&39;s", so he can perform a string search. One way could be to store "Mike's" in the database instead of "Mike&apos;s"...

Comment: @PatrickHofman Oops :-)

Comment: You could override `HttpEncoder`, though outputting `&apos;` isn't necessarily the best idea for that to do generally (since it's not allowed by all forms of HTML), and what are you going to do if you later come across `&#39;` or `&#x27;` or indeed `'` or any of the other valid HTML escapes?

Answer (score 4):

`apos` is an xml entity, not really HTML. You can use the AntiXSS library to encode as xml to get your apostrophes, but I don't know what other data you need to encode and if it will meet your needs but worth a try:

```
System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.XmlEncode("Mike's")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        string teststr = " > < & ";
        string zoo = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(teststr);
```

zoo ==  " & gt; & lt; & amp; " (Minus the spaces between the ampersand and alpha characters)

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "str'str";
```

**Option 1:**

```
System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(str);
```

**Option 2:**

```
string encoded = str.Replace("&", "&amp;").Replace("<", "&lt;").Replace(">", "&gt;").Replace("\"", "&quot;").Replace("'", "&apos;");
```

[for more info take a look at xml encoding](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)